# indexing arrays with arrays in numba (njit): variable-dimension ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I have a 1D array of integers with D elements (i.e. `idx = np.array([i0, i1, ...])`, s.t. `idx.size` = D), where each element corresponds to the index along that dimension of an ND array with D dimensions (i.e. `data` s.t. `data.ndim` = D).  How can I index the `data` array using the index array `idx`?

---

In python I would do `data[tuple(idx)]`, but `tuple` aren't supported in numba nopython mode.

My current workaround is to use `data.ravel()` and convert from ND indices to 1D indices of the flattened array, but it seems like there must be an easier (and computationally faster) solution.  Is there a `take_along_each_axis(data, idx)` method somewhere?

Comment: Why do you need to use `njit`?  This is a basic numpy operation, implemented in compiled code.  It isn't iterating in python.

Comment: `date.__getitem__(idx)`

Comment: @hpaulj My end goal is a slightly more complicated calculation than indexing an array.  `__getitem__()` using an array (instead of tuple) is the same as indexing with it, it sequentially gets each element instead of using each element to index each dimension, i.e. `data.__getitem__([0, 0, ... 0])` returns `data` itself, not the 0th entry.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do a bit of time testing:

```
In [135]: data = np.ones((100,100,100,100)); idx = (50,50,50,50)
```

That's nearly a Gb of memory - not huge enough to create a memory error, but still should be a reasonable test.  Actually, I get the same time for basic indexing for much smaller arrays.  And for other `idx` values

```
In [136]: timeit data[idx]
212 ns ± 9.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

the interpreter translates that into a method call:

```
In [137]: timeit data.__getitem__(idx)
283 ns ± 4.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

indexing the 'flat' array, can be done with:

```
In [138]: timeit data.flat[np.ravel_multi_index(idx,data.shape)]
6.65 µs ± 75.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

or taking the conversion out of the loop:

```
In [139]: %%timeit x=np.ravel_multi_index(idx,data.shape)
     ...: data.flat[x] 
574 ns ± 23.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [142]: %%timeit x=np.ravel_multi_index(idx,data.shape);df=data.flat
     ...: df[x]
345 ns ± 6.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I think there are cases where flat indexing is faster, but this isn't one.

So a stand alone operation I don't see the point to writing a `njit` version.  I suppose if it's part of some larger operation it could be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So, flattening is indeed more than 2 times slower.  And actually `ravel_multi_index` isn't implemented in numba so I had to write my own version which is possibly even slower (despite pre-caching the product of the array shape).